# How to duplicate a ListView item to a second ListView Activity

Tags: java, android, eclipse, listview

I have a problem that i can't understand how to solve.

Example:

I have a list view named Maps:

```
1 My Maps
2 France map
3 Germany map
4 Italy map
```

My Maps point to an Activity that contains a list view of downloaded maps.

France map, Germany map and Italy map, if clicked, start a map file download, or, if map file are already downloaded, it open the relative map.

What i need to understand is how to duplicate after the download, a list view item inside My Maps Activity

Example:

Before download:

```
1 My Maps   ------> no maps
2 France map
3 Germany map
4 Italy map
```

After the download of France map file:

```
1 My Maps   ------> France map  -------> open France map
2 France map ------- > open France map
3 Germany map
4 Italy map
```

What method i must use to obtain this result?

Thank you

This is the project so far:

MainActivity.java

```
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
    import android.widget.ListView;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener{

    ListView listView;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mapsList);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    }


    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position, long id) {
        switch (position){
         case 0:{
            Intent Info = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyMapsActivity.class);
        startActivity(Info);
          }
          break;
          case 1:{
          // do something
          }
          break;
          }

      }

   }
```

activity_main.xml

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android='http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android'
      android:layout_width='fill_parent'
      android:layout_height='fill_parent'
      android:orientation='vertical' >

      <ListView
        android:id="@+id/mapsList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:entries="@array/maps_array"
        />
   </LinearLayout>
```

MyMapsActivity.java

```
    import android.app.ListActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.Menu;



    public class MyMapsActivity extends ListActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mymaps);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

   }
```

strings.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
       <resources>

            <string name="app_name">Maps</string>
            <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>

            <string-array name="maps_array">
                <item>MyMaps</item>
                <item>France</item>
                <item>Germany</item>
                <item>Italy</item>
                <item>New York</item>
                <item>Hamburg</item>
                <item>Berlin</item>
           </string-array>

     </resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

My Maps, when clicked on, should start a new Activity (let's call it `MyMapsActivity`). MyMapsActivity will extend `ListActivity` just like whatever your current activity is doing. You'll need an array (or whatever) of the maps you have stored on the device, but then just adapt them for the ListView just like you're doing in the 1st activity, and again in `onListItemClick` take the user to the Activity that houses the specific map that has been downloaded.

Unless I'm misunderstanding your question, you should be able to sort of duplicate what you're already doing in your 1st activity for the new `MyMapsActivity`.